# These credentials do not match our records laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

**What i want**

I wanted to use the laravel authentication system that has been obtained by using `php artisan make:auth` command

---

**what happened**

- I can see the items that is registered by the register form but i am not able to log in through the app with those credentials.
- *Error*:These credentials do not match our records.

**What i did**

`php artisan make:Auth`

*User.php*

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableTrait;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable 
{
    protected $fillable=['name','password','email'];
    protected $table='blog_users';


    public function getAuthIdentifierName(){}
    public function getAuthIdentifier(){}
    public function getAuthPassword(){}
    public function getRememberToken(){}
    public function setRememberToken($value){}
    public function getRememberTokenName(){}
}
```

---

**What i tried**

I tried to provide my action methods but i still cannot log in through these credentials and i still see the same error.

---

**What i hope**

To get a better understanding about my problem and the solution about it?

---

**Snapshots**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Remove all method from model and try again.

Comment: it gives me an error saying it contains 6 abstract methods

Comment: @BOTJr. what is your laravel version?

Comment: it's 5.3.28 , i guess it's the latest one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what my Laravel 5.3 User model looked like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

I would assume all those empty methods would be causing problems for you.

Comment: yes, i did this and it worked , i am not sure why but it worked

Comment: Most likely because you were overriding all of the ```Authenticatable``` trait methods and they were empty

Answer (score 0):

Laravel compare the Hased password:

for this you need to store the password in either of the ways:

```
$password = bcrypt('secret');
```

or

```
$password = Hash::make('secret');
```

for Better understanding view this:-https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing

Hope this helps you.

Comment: How does this solves my problem? i know this already but why am i not be able to log?

Comment: Controller logic is the built one , that comes up  when you run this command.

Comment: It makes a logic controller file which uses a AuthenticateUsers file , which contains the whole logic

Comment: just a random solution can you try this:---
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;

and implement AuthorizableContract